# Can I install minikube on ubuntu without virtualBox?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, microk8s

I want to start practicing with k8s for the CKAD exam. I run on ubuntu 18.04.
I noticed everywhere that I need to download *Virtualbox* for *minikube*. I believe that *VB* is needed in case I don't start my cluster with a driver but if I use the *Docker* driver when I start my cluster shouldn't that be enough? Is microk8s a better option?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the preferred way is use --driver=docker driver instead of --driver=none for minikube, although **it is technically not baremetal** as it is significantly easier to configure and does not require root access. The ‘none’ driver is recommended for advanced users only. (info below from https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/)

docker
Overview

The Docker driver allows you to install Kubernetes into an existing Docker install. On Linux, this does not require virtualization to be enabled.
Requirements

- Install Docker 18.09 or higher
- amd64 or arm64 system.

Usage

Start a cluster using the docker driver:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

To make docker the default driver:

```
minikube config set driver docker
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Check [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#specifying-the-vm-driver).

> Minikube also supports a `--driver=none` option that runs the Kubernetes components on the host and not in a VM. Using this driver requires Docker and a Linux environment but not a hypervisor.

Jus run

```
$ minikube start
```

> **Caution:** If you use the none driver, some Kubernetes components run as privileged containers that have side effects outside of the Minikube environment. Those side effects mean that the none driver is not recommended for personal workstations

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I followed their documentation since my OS is Linux and I have Docker installed but a lot of the tutorials suggested installing VirtualBox and I was not entirely sure why since I don't want to use a different OS....or if it made a difference using minikube outside of VB

Comment: There is a caution, I updated answer. generally there is not other problem @fuschiapasty